# Solid front axle alignment - jeep wrangler

Tags: noise, suspension, jeep, steering, alignment

So I put some new suspensions on my jeep about a year ago. Nothing fancy, just coil springs, shocks and stabilizer bars, leaving the factory control arms etc in place.

It was a DIY job in my parking spot, so inevitably I messed something up and now there's an annoying creaking/popping sound whenever I turn the steering wheel at low speeds (i.e. when trying to park). It sounds like a bad bushing popping and clicking. Not metallic, just a dull/muted pop.

After spending many hours under the jeep I have given up on finding the cause myself. I'm planning on taking it to an alignment shop, but just wondering what they can do for a car with front and rear solid axles? Seems to me besides toe in/toe out there's nothing to be adjusted, since the control arms and stabilizer bars are all rigid?

Do you think they'd be able to find the source of the noise from doing an alignment? or any other suggestions on where the noise could be coming from? Apologies for the vague question, any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Fellow Jeeper here! Anytime you adjust the suspension, even with a straight forward lift, take it in for an alignment after.

What it sounds like here is a bad or failing axle u-joint. They’re fairly easy to replace given the right tools.

Answer (score 0):

Most axles have adjustment for other factors (kpi, bearing preload etc) built-in by using shims etc for the bearing mounts - need to provide details of the axle, manufacturer etc.

One possibility for the popping / clicking noise is that the bushes were tightened before the weight was back on the wheels and the bushes locked" in an extended position.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, an alignment pro will surely figure it out. Tell them about the noise after adding the lift.
Probably just something too loose or the new angles finished off a dry connecting rod end.